# Insert a blob file and retrieve it PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, blob

I know there are hundreds of questions like this but I still can't understand how to insert and retrieve a blob.

```
public function uploadContent($selectIDname, $incrementVersion, $data, $getAuthorID){
        $dbManager = DatabaseConnectivityManager::getInstance();
        $connection  = $dbManager->getConnection();
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, static::$insertIntoFilescontent);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "iisi",$selectIDname, $incrementVersion, $data, $getAuthorID);
        $uploadFilescontent = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
        return $uploadFilescontent;
    }
```

This is how i insert blobs ($data should be the blob but when in bind_param I put b nothing goes in the table, so i set it to string - s). When the user logs in he must see all his uploaded file.
Here's what i've tried but it doesn't work.

```
    $type = $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];
    $sql = "SELECT fileContent FROM filescontent WHERE author='$getAuthorID'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $data = $row['fileContent'];
    header("Content-type: $type");
    print $data;
```

Comment: Show us sql for `$insertIntoFilescontent`.

Comment: private static $insertIntoFilescontent = "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

Comment: How does that "not work"?  Do you see an error?  Does the browser ask to download a file?  Did you try to open that file in notepad or a hex editor?